# Asserting for a specific error using only standard library in golang

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

Let's suppose I have a function which return `base64` encoded string for a file which is located at a specific `path`.

```
func getFile(path string) (string, error) {
    imgFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Error opening image file: %s", err)
    }

    base64 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(imgFile)
    return base64, nil
}
```

Now, I'm writing table driven tests for this function and they right now look like this.

```
func TestGetFile(t *testing.T) {
    type getFileTest struct {
        Path   string
        Base64 string
        Err    error
    }

    getFileTests := []getFileTest{
        {"", "", nil},
    }
    for _, td := range getFileTests {
        base64, err := getFile(td.Path)
        if err != nil {
            t.Errorf("TestGetFile: Error calling getFile: %s", err)
        }
        if base64 != td.Base64 {
            t.Errorf("TestGetFile: Return values from getFile is not expected: Expected: %s, Returned: %s", td.Base64, base64)
        }
    }

}
```

Now, current test fails with:-

```
test.go:18: TestGetFile: Error calling getFile: Error opening image file: open : no such file or directory
```

How do I assert that I get the right error when I pass empty path to `getFile`?

Comment: I strongly recommend reading this: http://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/07/constant-errors

Answer (score 2):

The `os` package provides the [`os.IsNotExist`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#IsNotExist) function to check the various file existence errors:

```
if err != nil && os.IsNotExist(err) {
    fmt.Println("file doesn't exist")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, how am I supposed to integrate that in my table driven tests?

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi: what issue do you have checking the error in your tests?

Comment: I wanted to specify error as a value in my `getFileTests` array. Trying to fit in the table driven approach with this.

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi: I'm still not following. You can assign the error to the Err field and use `is.IsNotExist` to check it, or you could assign another known value for a non-existent file, like `os.ErrNotExist`, or your own error value.

Answer (score 1):

On a more general level, you can use a `strings.Contains()` call on `err.Error()` (which returns the string of the error message).  Example:

```
if err == nil || !strings.Contains(err.Error(), "no such file or directory") {
    // we didn't get the error we were expecting
}
```

Note, however, that string matching is rather fragile.  If the package author changes the error message, your test might start failing despite the correct error still being returned.

This is why the idiom in Go is usually for packages to define the error types they return as package-level constants, or more often, variables, since `fmt.Errorf()` and `errors.New()` return `error` interface types, which by definition can't be constant, since interfaces are reference types.  As package-level constants, they can be directly tested for.  Example, the `sql` package defines `sql.ErrNoRows`, so you can quickly and easily test if the error a query returned indicates that there were no result rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a "constant" and use it as a reference for comparison like that :

```
var ErrFile = errors.New("Error opening image file")

func getFile(path string) (string, error) {
    return "", ErrFile
}

func main() {
    f := "problem.txt"
    _, err := getFile(f)
    if err == ErrFile {
       fmt.Printf("Problem with file %s", f)
    }
}
```

[Test on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ORU4PE3zrI)

Or, if you need more flexibility, you can create your own error type.

```
type FileError struct {
    Path string
}

func (e *FileError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Error opening image file: %s", e.Path)
}

func getFile(path string) (string, error) {
    return "", &FileError{Path: path}
}

func main() {
    f := "problem.txt"
    _, err := getFile(f)
    if ferr, ok := err.(* FileError); ok {
        fmt.Println(ferr)
    }
}
```

[Test on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gduEPfo1Js)